# Quantum NOR Gate

Tags: quantum-gate

How to implement NOR gate functionality within a quantum circuit? Having $3$ input bits $f(x) \rightarrow y$, I would like to achieve $y=1$ every time when $x=?00$ is on input ($x=000$ or $x=100$).

Answer (score 1):

A possible implementation for **NOR** gate by using one **Toffoli** gate and **X** gates:

[image]

Note that the last qubit is always in the $|0\rangle$ state and the output of this implementation for **NOR** gate will be stored in the state of that qubit. The first two qubits are for the input state.
[Here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11674/9459) one can find more about similar gates. The main idea is that the **X** gate will be applied only if both top qubits are in $|0\rangle$ state, otherwise, the gate(s) will do nothing. Hence the action on different inputs look like this $|000\rangle \rightarrow |100\rangle$, $|001\rangle \rightarrow |001\rangle$, $|010\rangle \rightarrow |010\rangle$, $|011\rangle \rightarrow |011\rangle$ (the bottom qubit is the leftmost qubit in this notation).